# Minecraft Server crashing overnight (using too many threads?)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, server-administration

Okay, i can't seem to find any articles related to my problem, so i'm asking here.

So, i have a google cloud VM, which has one core and one thread (checked with `lscpu | egrep 'Model name|Socket|Thread|NUMA|CPU\(s\)'`) and 3.6Gi of RAM running Ubuntu

I'm running Bukkit and my minecraft version is 1.16.5

Here are the plugins i have:
[image: Here are the plugins i have]

So usually the server works fine, aside from some of the plugins that should be stable (serversigns) acting weird, but every time i leave it running for the night and come back the next day, it has crashed. crash-reports doesn't have any logs.

The folder that i have the server jarfile in has some logs in this pattern: `hs_err_pid11770.log` but i can't figure out what's the latest. I have written the error that occured the most below.

I think the problem is that Java is trying to use more threads than the VM has.

```
[06:13:38 INFO]: Using 4 threads for Netty based IO
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Is this even the problem?

**hs_err_pid11770.log:**

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 16384 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native$
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Zero Based Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 32GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 32GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2922), pid=11770, tid=15191
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.9.1+1) (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Debian-1deb10u2)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.9.1+1-post-Debian-1deb10u2, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, serial $
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" b$
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xms3500M -Xmx3500M paperserver.jar -nogui

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz, 1 cores, 3G, Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Time: Thu Apr  8 19:34:31 2021 UTC elapsed time: 23858.828009 seconds (0d 6h 37m 38s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f485c0f2000):  JavaThread "luckperms-scheduler-worker-116" daemon [_thread_new, id=15191, s$
```

.

Here's some errors i get while starting the server and a little while after that if they're of any use.

```
[06:14:37 WARN]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.compat.v1_16_R3.InventoryHandler
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:182)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:111)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.factory.HandlerFactory.getNewInstance(HandlerFactory.java:13)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.factory.InventoryHandlerFactory.getNewInstance(InventoryHandlerFactory.java:10)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.InventoryUtil.<clinit>(InventoryUtil.java:42)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.serializers.ConfigSerializer.getTransitionOptions(ConfigSerializer.java:544)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.serializers.BAConfigSerializer.parseOptionSets(BAConfigSerializer.java:283)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.serializers.BAConfigSerializer.loadDefaults(BAConfigSerializer.java:86)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.BattleArena.onEnable(BattleArena.java:218)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:380)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:483)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:501)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:415)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:580)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:280)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1055)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:289)
[06:14:37 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)§
```

and

```
[06:14:39 WARN]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.compat.v1_16_R3.SignHandler
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:182)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:111)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.factory.HandlerFactory.getNewInstance(HandlerFactory.java:13)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.factory.SignHandlerFactory.getNewInstance(SignHandlerFactory.java:10)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.SignUtil.<clinit>(SignUtil.java:12)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.listeners.SignUpdateListener.updateAttachedBlock(SignUpdateListener.java:80)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.listeners.SignUpdateListener.updateSign(SignUpdateListener.java:59)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.listeners.SignUpdateListener.updateAllSigns(SignUpdateListener.java:36)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at mc.alk.arena.BattleArena$1.run(BattleArena.java:275)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:100)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:468)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1064)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:289)
[06:14:39 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

and

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: plugins/Updater/config.yml (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration.load(FileConfiguration.java:126) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:gi
t-Paper-575]
        at mc.alk.arena.alib.battlepluginupdater.GitHubUpdater.update(GitHubUpdater.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at mc.alk.arena.BattleArena.onEnable(BattleArena.java:293) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-575]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:380) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git
-Paper-575]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:483) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:gi
t-Paper-575]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:501) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-
Paper-575]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:415) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git
-Paper-575]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:580) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:g
it-Paper-575]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:280) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Pa
per-575]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1055) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Pape
r-575]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:289) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:
git-Paper-575]
```

I installed BattleBukkitLib (downloaded jarfile, put in plugins folder) and got this error:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:162) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-575]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:148) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-575]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:389) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-575]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:251) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-575]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1055) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-575]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:289) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-575]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
        ... 7 more
```

I've tried starting the server with `-XX:CICompilerCount=1`, but it won't start without the CompilerCount being 4.

**I solved this issue by setting the ram amount lover in the java command and using aikar's flags""

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not support modded Minecraft (or modded servers). However, something that could help us figure out your crash issue would be a list of plugins that you are running and the full crash log (you can find it in your respective `logs/XXX.log`).

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean Bukkit by modded servers?

Comment: yes, all your plugins and such are mods

Comment: Just a heads up, that isn't the full crash log. You can find it at the bottom of your server logs ie. `logs/latest.log`

Answer (score 2):

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

Get a better server (install more RAM), or check if there aren't memory leaks in one of your plugins.

Something has gone very wrong in [LuckPerms](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/luckperms.28140/). Try reporting it to the developer, however, from what I can see there isn't very much he could use to recreate your issue.

---

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.compat.v1_16_R3.SignHandler
> ```

and

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mc.alk.arena.alib.battlebukkitlib.compat.v1_16_R3.InventoryHandler
> ```

You're missing a jar file; dependency somewhere. Try:

- https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/battlearena.37552/
- https://github.com/BattlePlugins/BattleBukkitLib

However, these are warnings (and not fatal errors) and means you probably don't need to worry about it since the developer probably did code handling it.

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: plugins/Updater/config.yml (Is a directory)
> ```

You're missing a config file from some sort of updater, or plugin called "Updater".

Comment: I thought almost 4Gi RAM was decent for a server, at least for one with usually only 3 players online? How do i check for memory leaks?

Comment: You watch the server resources monitor. The default one in Linux is `top`. Literally watch it for say... An hour, and see if server resources go up over time even when idle. Also, by "full log", I mean is there anything more to that crash `.log` (ie. other threads), and check the bottom of your `latest.log` or `2021-03-20-1.log.gz` (unzip these first). It is likely it is a bug and you should report it to the developer.